# image that has 100% height and stretches to the right and left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for CSS (preferred) or javascript/jquery where i have an image that has a height of `100%`. The image should maintain aspect ratio and if the width of the screen is smaller than the width of the image it should be cropped equally from left and right. Basically the image should be centered in the `div`

[image]

Comment: does it have to be an `img`? `background-size` can use `cover` or `contain` which sounds like what you're going for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size here's an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmEdME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `object-fit:cover;` it crops your image.

```
#image {
    width: 100%;;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit:cover
 }
```

Plus with `@media` you can just adapt the image to your screen resolution.

Comment: it's worth noting that doesn't work at all in IE http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: He's asking for "a" solution, this is as fast I could think of, IE is a different problem. Plus he didn't include which browsers he wanted it available in

Comment: It's a valid answer, not trying to imply otherwise - I'm just worth noting it probably isn't a production solution at the moment.

Comment: It's always open for other sugestions if you have any ✌ stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Flexbox:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="http://blog.conservation.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ci_19290600_cropped.jpg" />
</div>
```

2. You can put the image as a background of the DIV:

```css
.image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 500px;  /* whatever you need */
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://blog.conservation.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ci_19290600_cropped.jpg);"></div
```